# Derivative of t distribution probability density function

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics

For the standard normal density function $\phi(x)$ we have the following equality
$$
\frac{d\phi}{dx}=-x\phi(x)
$$
Is there something similar for the Student's t distribution? In other words, is it possible to **express its derivative in terms of its pdf**?

Comment: Yes, a 2-min google search returns https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458304/student-t-distribution-as-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for [corey979](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/72352/corey979)'s response with [this reference](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2458304/student-t-distribution-as-a-solution-of-a-differential-equation). The answer is:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}t_{\nu}=-\frac{\nu+1}{\nu+x^2}xt_{\nu}(x)
$$